# How to paste the text in command-line mode in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I have copied a word to search from the file.

Is there a command to paste that word in command-line mode.

For eg. I have copied the word 'static' from the code below in default register and I want to paste that in command-line mode, as below

/static

```
1275 static const struct of_device_id omap_mcspi_of_match[] = {
1276         {
1277                 .compatible = "ti,omap2-mcspi",
1278                 .data = &omap2_pdata,
1279         },
1280         {
1281                 .compatible = "ti,omap4-mcspi",
1282                 .data = &omap4_pdata,
1283         },
1284         { },
1285 };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While in either command mode or in search mode, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to paste from the default register. That is, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, release it and then type <kbd>"</kbd>.

For any other named register, you can just to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by the name of the register, like `a` or `b`.

Alternately, if you enter search mode using the command `q/` instead of just `/`, you can simply use `p` to paste, the same way you would in a normal buffer.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

- Check `:h c_^r`. On the command-line you can say `/<C-R>"` to copy the contents of the default register " and it will get converted to `/static`
- Alternately, a more convenient way (in most cases) is to use `:h c_^r^w` to copy the current word under the cursor denoted by `<cword>`. So you can say `/<C-R><C-W>` and that will get converted to `/static` given that your cursor is on the word static.

Comment: : `<C-R>"` answers the question as asked, but `<C-R><C-W>` is almost certainly the answer to the underlying problem!

Answer (score 5):

What about simply hitting `*` with the cursor in `static`?

Comment: Agreed, if the intent was merely to search for the word, this would be the most effective solution.

Comment: @merlin2011 If the intent was to built a pattern including the word this solution is still usable: After pressing `*` you can press `/` and `<UP>` to get the last search pattern, which is the word.